# jQuery Property Tax Calculator

Tags: jquery, math

I'm trying to make a pretty simple form calculator with jQuery ...

```
<form>
<label for="taxableValue">Enter your property’s TAXABLE Value</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="taxableValue" placeholder="TAXABLE Value">
<div class="radio">

<!--Radio group-->
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" name="millageRate" type="radio" id="radio100" value="0.6043">
<label class="form-check-label" for="radio100">$20 million bond issuance (.6043 mills)</label>

</div>
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" name="millageRate" type="radio" id="radio101" value="0.9046">
<label class="form-check-label" for="radio101">$30 million bond issuance (.9046 mills)</label>

</div>

<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" name="millageRate" type="radio" id="radio102" value="1.2051">
<label class="form-check-label" for="radio102">$40 million bond issuance (1.2051 mills)</label>

</div>
</div>
<div class="result"></div>

    </form>
```

This is my jQuery code ...

```
function compute() {
if ( $('select[name=millageRate]:checked').val() != undefined ) {
    var a = $('input[name=taxableValue]:number').val();
    var b = $('input[name=millageRate]:checked').val();
    var result = (taxableValue / 1000) * millageRate;
   }
};
$('input[name=taxableValue]').change(compute);
$('select[name=millageRate]').change(compute);

}
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

I am not a real coder, as you can probably tell, I just try hard.

Dan

Comment: Can *you* first tell what's wrong? What happens and what did you expect to happen instead? Are there error messages in the console?

Comment: Okay, I expected the "result" div to display the calculation on any change to the "milagesRate" radios, or the "taxableValue" field.

Comment: The `millageRate` element isn't a `select`, so that selector is incorrect. `val()` also returns a string (empty or otherwise) so the `!= undefined` check will always hit.

Comment: Also, you calculate the result but you don't do anything with it.

Comment: Do not create the change event binding inside the compute function.  It will create new ones each time the function runs.  Create them outside that method, only once.

Comment: How should I change the code?

Comment: have u give complete jquery code. as one '}' bracket seems to be extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script there were a few things wrong.

1. Conditional is not a select element.
2. var A value is not set correctly
3. var result is using two undeclared variables
4. You end your function before using result
5. You do not change the value of result.

Here is how I believe it should look for your intended function.

```
function compute() {
    if ( $('input[name=millageRate]:checked').val() != undefined ) {
        var a = $('#taxableValue').val();
        var b = $('input[name=millageRate]:checked').val();
        var result = (a / 1000) * b;
    }
    $('#result').text(result);
}
```

Then in your HTML add a button that will run this function when clicked.

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="compute()"></input>
```

Here is the full code I used to get it to work.

```
<form>
  <label for="taxableValue">Enter your property’s TAXABLE Value</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taxableValue" placeholder="TAXABLE Value">
  <div class="radio">

  <!--Radio group-->
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="millageRate" type="radio" id="radio100" value="0.6043">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radio100">$20 million bond issuance (.6043 mills)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="millageRate" type="radio" id="radio101" value="0.9046">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radio101">$30 million bond issuance (.9046 mills)</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" name="millageRate" type="radio" id="radio102" value="1.2051">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="radio102">$40 million bond issuance (1.2051 mills)</label>
  </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="compute()"></input>
  <script>
    function compute() {
      if ( $('input[name=millageRate]:checked').val() != undefined ) {
        var a = $('#taxableValue').val();
        var b = $('input[name=millageRate]:checked').val();
        var result = (a / 1000) * b;
      }
      $('#result').text(result);
    }
  </script>
  <div class="result" id="result"></div> 
</form>
```

If you do not want a button as the controlling field, you can instead remove it, and add listeners to radio group and text field to accomplish the same result.

```
$(function(){
  var compute = function(){
    if ( $('input[name=millageRate]:checked').val() != undefined ) {
      var a = $('#taxableValue').val();
      var b = $('input[name=millageRate]:checked').val();
      var result = (a / 1000) * b;
    }
    $('#result').text(result);  
  }
  $('#taxableValue').on("keyup", compute);
  $('form').on("change", compute);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Greg. That does work. I was hoping to do it without the button,

Comment: Provided an additional example for using this without a button.